# Template function where one of the arguments need specialization and the other does not

Tags: c++, templates

I am working in a graph and I want to make some searches in a directed graph, in one case with the edges pointing as usual, and in the other case with the edges in the reverse direction. The edges have a time to transverse them. This time is not necessarily a fixed value or member of the class, and they can have different duration types (`std::chrono::seconds`, `std::chrono::milliseconds`, ...).
For each of the two cases, I need a function to add time. This function is different in these two cases, and for each one it should also be a template because the duration type can be different.

My idea is to do something like the following:

```cpp
class ForwardEdge;
class ReverseEdge;

template<typename DurationType>
std::chrono::time_point time_sum<ForwardEdge>(std::chrono::time_point tp, DurationType inc) {
  return tp + inc;
}
template<typename DurationType>
std::chrono::time_point time_sum<ReverseEdge>(std::chrono::time_point tp, DurationType inc) {
  return tp - inc;
}
```

What would be the right way to do this?

Comment: You first of all need to declare the base two-template variant before the specializations. Please read more about [partial template specialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/partial_specialization).

Comment: ...next you will find out the partial specialization is not allowed for function templates, but this can be worked around by partially specialzing a type instead

Comment: If you always have access to an instance of `ForwardEdge` or `ReverseEdge` when calling `time_sum`, you can simply add a dumb argument `ForwardEdge const&` or `ReverseEdge const&`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you can partial specialize a template function.

If you accept a solution based on a `struct` with a (static?) template function in it, you can specialize the `struct`.

I mean... something as follows

```
template <typename>
struct struct_sum;

template <>
struct struct_sum<ForwardEdge>
{
  template <typename DurationType>
  static std::chrono::time_point func(std::chrono::time_point tp,
                                      DurationType inc)
  { return tp + inc; }
};


template <>
struct struct_sum<ReverseEdge>
{
  template <typename DurationType>
  static std::chrono::time_point func(std::chrono::time_point tp,
                                      DurationType inc)
  { return tp - inc; }
};
```

that you can use this way

```
struct_sum<ForwardEdge>::func(tp, inc);
```

Answer (score 0):

Before you can specialise a template, you first have to introduce it at all:

```
template<typename Edge, typename DurationType>
std::chrono::time_point time_sum(std::chrono::time_point tp, DurationType inc);

template<typename DurationType>
std::chrono::time_point time_sum<ForwardEdge, DurationType>( /*...*/ )
//                                   ^^^            ^^^
// you still need to specify ALL template parameters!
```

Solely: This is a *partial* specialisation! You are not allowed to partially specialise functions, you are *only* allowed to do so on *types*.

So we'd need a helper class:

```
template<typename Edge, typename DurationType>
struct TimeSum;

template<typename DurationType>
struct TimeSum<ForwardEdge, DurationType>
{
    std::chrono::time_point operator()(std::chrono::time_point tp, DurationType d)
    {
        return tp + d;
    }
};

template<typename DurationType>
struct TimeSum<ReverseEdge>
{
    std::chrono::time_point operator()(std::chrono::time_point tp, DurationType d)
    {
        return tp - d;
    }
};
```

Now we can use the types in a entirely non-specialised function:

```
template<typename Edge, typename DurationType>
std::chrono::time_point time_sum(std::chrono::time_point tp, DurationType inc)
{
    return TimeSum<Edge, DurationType>()(tp, inc);
    //              ^^^
    // selects appropriate partial specialisation
}
```

So far, we only get those two specialisations, any other template instantiations remain undefined. A variant might be:

```
template<typename Edge, typename DurationType>
{
    std::chrono::time_point operator()(std::chrono::time_point tp, DurationType d)
    {
        return tp + d;
    }
};

// and the specialisation for ReverseEdge from above
```

In this scenario, you have a general template that works for any type not covered by the specialisation (including `ForwardEdge`) and a specialisation specific to `ReverseEdge`. Considering the name of the type (`TimeSum`), this might be the more appropriate variant.

As there's no edge function parameter, though, you'd need to specify the template argument manually. If you *do* have edges available anyway, overloads might be better choice:

```
template<typename DurationType>
std::chrono::time_point time_sum
(
    ForwardEdge const&, // <--
    std::chrono::time_point tp, DurationType inc
);

template<typename DurationType>
std::chrono::time_point time_sum
(
    ReverseEdge const&, // <--
    std::chrono::time_point tp, DurationType inc
);
```

Another alternative could be having *member* functions in each class (possibly even virtual, if these share a common base).

Comment: You are not specializing since the initial `time_sum` only has a `DurationType` template argument, not a "edge" template argument. And even in this case, you cannot partially specialize.

Comment: Oh, overlooked a detail... So there are *two* template parameters! OK, give me some time to adjust.